# Require_once not working in PHP script

Tags: php, require-once

I am making a wordpress plugin and I am having a little issue with this paragraph of code. For some reason

```
echo "<table style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Total Submission Sites</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Server Status</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Plugin Version</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Latest Update</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'> <?php require_once('http://wert.in/pluginfiles/files/v101/v101.php') ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled? Normally it's not so you can't include/require remote files (which is a hideous security hole)

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the require into the echo, or it will just display the text and not parse the function. You need to end the echo with a "; then the require, and then output again. Or you can use echo "something" . require(blah) . "end"; but I didn't use this for simplicities sake. Also, the require uses a local path/file not remote. This is the equivelent of trying to open a URL in Notepad on your computer, when its looking for something on your hard drive instead.

```
// start the echo
echo "<table style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Total Submission Sites</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Server Status</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Plugin Version</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Latest Update</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>";

// Still using php, dont need the opening tag. 
require_once('http://wert.in/pluginfiles/files/v101/v101.php');

// Finish the echo
echo "</td>
  </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Didn't even catch that the URL is external. This may cause a problem, like noted in the initial comment above. require_once looks for a local file, i.e: /pluginfiles/files/v101/v101.php not a URL.

Answer (score 1):

why echo a whole string and not without and only `<?php require_once( [.....] ); ?>`

```
<table style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Total Submission Sites</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Server Status</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Plugin Version</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>Latest Update</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'>test</td>
    <td style='border:solid 1px #000000;'><?php require_once('./pluginfiles/files/v101/v101.php') ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just make sure that if this is just a chuck of a larger file using PHP, you need to use a php end tag, and opening tag again before and after. i.e:      ?>TrickerAnswerHere<?php

Comment: He is tellin he is using Wordpress, and in that case i would use it like this. Because Wordpress is using it in this way.

But if there is MORE PHP then HTML then i should do it with a echo

Comment: Thanks tricker this worked perfectly as well as with the repsonse with david :)